# VIM command for backspace to remove a empty line

Tags: vim

I have a virtual server with debian lenny, when editing files I have been forced to use VIM.

I have been teaching myself although can't figure out how to remove a blank line after removing a line of text, this doesn't work like I would expect. This is editing the crontab

Comment: Ok figured out how to save a file using `:wq`

Comment: What does saving have to do with your question about backspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good one for you that's often cited:

**Learn Vim Progressively**

*Want to learn vim (the best text editor known to human kind) the fastest way possible. I suggest you a way. Start by learning the minimal to survive, then integrate slowly all tricks.*

http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/

Comment: You did not even answer the question!